# How to make API requests correctly with Reactjs and Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using the latest version of **ReactJS** and making requests with **Axios**. But before I entered the `cancel()` function I was getting the following error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in MenuPlaylist (at Sidebar/index.js:19)
    in aside (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.aside)
    in styled.aside (at Sidebar/index.js:11)
    in Sidebar (at Search/index.js:16)
    in Search (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Because the problem was as soon as the component disassembled it leaked the memory. But now canceling the request I get the following messages on the console:

[image]
And I find it quite strange, as it seems that the system is in trouble.

**What is the correct way to cancel requests to avoid memory leaks?**

**COMPONENT:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// STYLES
import { Menu, Title } from "./styles";

// SERVICES
import { cancelAxiosRequest, getAllPlaylist } from "services/Api";

// SUBCOMPONENT'S
import { CreatePlaylist, CreatedPlaylist } from "components";

class MenuPlaylist extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  // LIFE CYCLES
  componentDidMount() {
    this.consumeAPI();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    cancelAxiosRequest("Request Canceled.");
  }

  // METHODS
  consumeAPI = () => {
    getAllPlaylist().then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ data: data });
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Menu>
        <Title>PLAYLISTS</Title>
        <CreatePlaylist />
        <CreatedPlaylist data={this.state.data} />
      </Menu>
    );
  };
}

export default MenuPlaylist;
```

**AXIOS:**

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
  timeout: 1000
});

let CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
export let cancelAxiosRequest;

// GET'S
export function getNewReleases() {
  return instance.get("/newReleases");
}

export function getAllPlaylist() {
  return instance.get("/playlist", {
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      cancelAxiosRequest = c;
    })
  });
}

export function getPlaylist(name) {
  return instance.get("/playlist", {
    params: {
      name: name
    }
  });
}

// POST'S
export function postNewPlaylist(id, name) {
  return instance.post("/playlist", {
    id: id,
    to: `/playlist/${id}`,
    name: name
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) "cancelling" means the promise throws a Cancel error with the message you specify.

to fix:

```
// ...

getAllPlaylist()
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({ data });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
      return; // ignore
    }
    throw err; // or handle other errors
  });

// ...
```

Though I feel changing the value of an export is not really the best way to use cancel tokens. Check if you need to be unmounting the component in the first place, but if it truly is just going to be unmounted sometimes, maybe try something like

```
export function getAllPlaylist(cancelToken) {
  return instance.get("/playlist", {
    cancelToken: cancelToken
  });
}

// ...

getAllPlaylist(new CancelToken(c => this.cancel = c))
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({ data });
  });

// ...

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.cancel();
}
```

I don't know if this is 100% ideal, but this avoids multiple instances of the component fighting over a single variable.

Comment: Is there a better way, with good practices when dismounting the component does not give memory leak due to the API call?

Answer (score 0):

in the catch you should do something like

```
.catch((e) => {
        if (axios.isCancel(e)) return;
        setError(true);
      });
```

because canceling isn't an error